# Getting error while writing else case statement in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I have a query in which I have to do filtering using case statement. It seems every case condition is getting executed:

```
declare @filterValue varchar(50)='test'
    declare @filterCol varchar(50)='DayOfWeekAbr'

    select * from datetable where 1=1 and (
    case when @filterCol='' then DayOfWeekAbr
     when @filterCol='' then [WeekOfYear]
    end = @filterValue
    OR case when ISNULL(@filterCol,'')='' then 1
    end =1)
```

Getting error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test' to data type int.

Now the error is because column WeekOfYear is int. But my doubt is if the case statrement doesnot match the condition why it is executing it? And solution how to do it.

---

When implemented in the query below getting same error tell me where I am wrong:

```
   SELECT
                [threat_feed].[Id]
              , [threat_feed].[Name]
              , [threat_feed].[Url]
              , [threat_feed].[RefreshRate]
              , [threat_feed].[ConfidenceLevel]
              , [threat_feed].[Severity]
              , [threat_feed].[Type]
              , [threat_feed].[Source]
              , [threat_feed].[Description]
              , [threat_feed].[Visibility]
              , [threat_feed].[Integration]
              , [threat_feed].[IntegrationOptions]
              , [threat_feed].[CreatedBy]
              , [threat_feed].[CreatedOn]
              , [threat_feed].[ModifiedBy]
              , [threat_feed].[ModifiedOn]
              , [threat_feed].[IsDeleted]
              , COUNT(*) OVER () AS [TOTALROWS]

            FROM    [dbo].[ThreatFeed] [threat_feed]
            WHERE   [threat_feed].[IsDeleted] IN (0, @IncludeDeleted) AND (
        (@filterCol = 'Name' and [threat_feed].[Name]  =  @filterValue) or
        (@filterCol = 'Source' and [threat_feed].[Source] = @filterValue) or
        (@filterCol = 'URL' and [threat_feed].[Url] = @filterValue) or
        (@filterCol = 'RefreshRate' and [threat_feed].[RefreshRate]  =  @filterValue) or
        (@filterCol = 'ConfidenceLevel' and [threat_feed].[ConfidenceLevel] = @filterValue) or
        (@filterCol = 'Severity' and [threat_feed].[Severity] = @filterValue) or
        (@filterCol = 'Visibility' and [threat_feed].[Visibility] = @filterValue) or
        (isnull(@filterCol,'')='')
        )
```

Here confidencelevel, serverity and visibility is not varchar

Comment: The logic in your `CASE` statement makes no sense.

Comment: is [WeekOfYear] actually an int?  you seem to be comparing a string to an int - possibly not to do with CASE as such

Comment: oh right you know that anyway - why post an  error if you know what it is?  Why not fix your error, and see how it goes?

Comment: Andrew I tried that but couldnt find solution

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably the `case` expression in the `where`.  To be honest, this is more simply done without the `case`.  I think this is what you want:

```
where ( (@filterCol = 'DayOfWeekAbr' and DayOfWeekAbr =  @filterValue) or
        (@filterCol = 'WeekOfYear' and WeekOfYear = @filterValue) or
        (@filterCol is null)
      )
```

EDIT:

Oh, this is very interesting.  SQL (in general) does not guarantee lazy evaluation of boolean expressions.  So, both sides of the `or` might be evaluated . . . and this can cause a problem when the filter value is a string, but the column expects a number.

Here is one solution:

```
where (case when @filterCol = 'Name' and [threat_feed].[Name] = @filterValue) then 1
            when @filterCol = 'Source' and [threat_feed].[Source] = @filterValue)
            then 1
            . . .
        end) = 1
```

Then, just be sure that all the string columns are before the date columns.  The clauses in a `case` *are* guaranteed to be searched in order.

Another possibility, in SQL Server 2012+, is to use `try_convert()` for the non-string columns.  SO, if `RefreshRate` is an integer:

```
where . . .
        (@filterCol = 'URL' and [threat_feed].[Url] = @filterValue) or
        (@filterCol = 'RefreshRate' and [threat_feed].[RefreshRate]  =  try_convert(int, @filterValue) ) or
```

Comment: adding query on the top